# Can't reset the compute emulator of Windows Azure

Tags: azure

It seems that something goes wrong in my compute emulator and I can't use it normally, so I followed the instruction here to try to reset my emulator:

> write-host "========= Resetting Azure Comoute Emulator & Dev Storage...  ========="
>
> $CSRunFile = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe"
>
> $DSInitFile = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devstore\DSInit.exe"
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devstore:shutdown")
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devfabric:shutdown")
>
> Start-Process $DSInitFile @("/ForceCreate", "/silent") -Wait
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devfabric:shutdown")
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devfabric:clean")
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devfabric:start")
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/devstore:start")
>
> & $CSRunFile @("/removeAll")
>
> write-host "Resetting Azure Comoute Emulator & Dev Storage Done!"

But I blocked when I tried to shutdown the `/devfabric`

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator>csrun.exe /devfabric:shutdown
>
> Windows(R) Azure(TM) Desktop Execution Tool version 1.8.0.0 for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 4.0
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Shutting down the compute emulator...
>
> Using session id 1
>
> ^C
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator>

I can't get a respond for a long time.

Anyone could help with it?

Comment: "Azure Comoute Emulator" is my favorite emulator. :-P

Answer (score 0):

There could be one ore more specific reasons about your problem mostly specific to your machine configuration so looking the log is the best way to progress further. There are couple of of things you could try as below to troubleshoot the problem:

First check what is your dftemp root. If you haven't made any changes the default DfTemp root is set to as below (unless you have changed it):

- C:\Users_your_windows_login_name\AppData\Local

The computer emulator logs are located as:

- C:\Users_your_windows_login_name\AppData\Local\dftemp
- C:\Users_your_windows_login_name\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage

In above "dftemp" folder you will find df specific logs at:

- C:\Users_your_windows_login_name\AppData\Local\dftmp\DFAgentLogs
- C:\Users_your_windows_login_name\AppData\Local\dftmp\DevFCLogs

Now if you check "DFAgentLogs" you will see the latest logs which will show where CSRUN is stuck. Keep in mind if you have custom dftemp setup then the logs will be shown there. Once you have logs you will see if there is any exception or something noteworthy.

To further troubleshoot this issue, you can also run "[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)" in your machine and collect logs related with csrun process and see what could be the issue. 
[image]

Once you have above info either you can resolve the issue by your own or open Free Support Incident with [Windows Azure Support team](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) to get some help.